# Recaptcha.create works locally but not on server

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I've got an Google Recaptcha it uses the Recaptcha.create. However for some reason the Recaptcha.create works locally but not on the server. Here is my html and js.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
<div id="recaptcha"></div>
<div id="fError">Waiting for input.</div>
<script src="/assets/js/upload-flash.js"></script>
```

And this is the upload-flash.js

```
var captchaused = false;
function showRecaptcha() {
    Recaptcha.create("6LfHYvgSAAAAAJ9G7fNYW5vwQkxUZDNSFhweiOPp", "recaptcha", {
      theme: "clean",
      callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field});
}

function fileSelected() {
    var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    if (file) {
        if(captchaused === false){
            captchaused = true;
            showRecaptcha();
        } else {
            Recaptcha.reload();
        }
    }
}
/*... and after this comes the uploading part. Removed it so that it doesn't become too long*/
```

Here are pictures

Local

[image: local]

Server

[image: Server]

Comment: Check browser's console for error messages.

Comment: @Cheery There are none.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using valid public key? Google does not check it when it is used at localhost. `By default, all keys work on "localhost" (or "127.0.0.1"), so you can always develop and test on your local machine.`

Comment: @Cheery The server I'm using is my local in home server so its from 192.168.0.20 oh. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is not a localhost, even with private IP if domain is different from `localhost`. You need to create keys specific for your 'domain' - https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Comment: @Cheery However the key I'm using from google is saying that its a global key and works across all domains

Comment: `However the key I'm using from google is saying that its a global key and works across all domains` Never heard about such kind of a key. Also, google search does not find it anywhere.

Comment: Ooooh. I think I see it now. I'm using the wrong key. This is the one key im supposed to use. http://prntscr.com/4ysz2s. However the one I'm using is a different one. I'm gonna check if after this it works.

Comment: Any key will work with localhost, I cited it above. So you have a key with valid structure/length, but it will not work on the website if domain is different from localhost. You need a pair of public and private keys specific for your 'domain'.

Comment: @Cheery It works now. Such a stupid mistake I made. Thanks a lot Cheery. If you want the points for answering I'll gladly accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake with the public and private keys I get from google and used the wrong ones. After changing the keys I used it started working perfectly again.